# how to pass variables though javascript to ajax using jquery-tabledit?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am currently using the jquery plugin [Tabledit](http://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/#examples) and when i use an inline edit as in example 3 it calls my php page. I have no idea how to pass the changes I made in the edit to the new php page so i can change it in the database. it changes when you hit enter. (im guessing on enter it calls the edittask.php)

**html** here is one section of the table.  it changes on hitting enter after you type in new text.

```
<td class="tabledit-view-mode"> <span class=" tabledit-span ">header text</span>
    <input class="tabledit-input form-control input-sm" type="text" name="description" value=" " style="display: none;" disabled="" />
</td>
```

**javascript**

```
$('#thetable').Tabledit({
    url: 'editTask.php',
    editButton: false,
    deleteButton: false,
    columns: {
        identifier: [0, 'id'],
        editable: [
            [1, 'Header'],
            [2, 'Description']
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According this [sample](https://github.com/markcell/jquery-tabledit/blob/master/example.php), in your php script you can use variables from the POST array. In your case: `$_POST['description']` and `$_POST['header']`.

I mean:

**index.php**:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example3">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Header 1</td>
        <td>Description 1</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#example3').Tabledit({
            url: 'example.php',
            editButton: false,
            deleteButton: false,
            hideIdentifier: true,
            columns: {
                identifier: [0, 'id'],
                editable: [[1, 'header'], [2, 'description']]
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**example.php:**

```
print_r($_POST); 
// Array ( [id] => 1 [header] => Header 123 [action] => edit )
// Implement your logic here...
```

Comment: Hello. I have somewhat a similar problem with this one. I hope you can help me out. Here's mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35764986/pass-and-get-id-from-javascipt-to-php-controller/35765129