# Pass and Get ID from JavaScript to PHP Controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii, frontend

I have an inline editable table (I used [Tabledit](http://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/) for this) and each row has an ID and the IDs should be passed to the controller action (Yii2) in order for me to save edited data to the database. Here's my Tabledit code in my js file:

```
file.assetID = info.response; // the ID

for (var i = 0; i < file.length; i++) { // the table
    if (file[i].type == "image/jpeg") {
        var type = "photo";
    } else if (file[i].type == "video/mp4") {
        var type = "video";
    }

    messageHtml += '<tr id="' + file[i].assetID + '">';
    messageHtml += '<td style="display:none;" id="' + file[i].assetID + '">' + file[i].assetID + '</td>';
    messageHtml += '<td>' + file[i].name + '</td>';
    messageHtml += '<td>' + type + '</td>';
    messageHtml += '<td>' + file[i].size + " KB" + '</td>';
    messageHtml += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Tag"></td>';
    messageHtml += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Description"></td>';
    messageHtml += '</tr>';
}

var urlID = "../save-inline-edit/" + file[0].assetID; // url plus the ID of the row
$('#uploader_table').Tabledit({
    url: urlID,
    columns: {
        identifier: [0, 'id'],                    
        editable: [[1, file.name]/*, [3, file.tag], [4, file.description]*/]
    },
    onSuccess: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(jqXHR);
    },
    onFail: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(file.assetID);
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

I was expecting that it would point to the url specified (`urlID` where `save-inline-edit` is an action function in my controller--`public function actionSaveInlineEdit($id){...}`) after saving the inline edit, but as I inspect element (after saving), it gives me this error: 
[image]

Then I placed a `console.log` to view the error details and I get this:
[image]

> "Bad Request (#400): Missing required parameters: id"

Here's my controller action:

```
public function actionSaveInlineEdit($id)
{
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $assetModel = $this->findModel($id);

    $input = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);

    if ($input['action'] === 'edit') {
        $assetModel->title = "";
        $assetModel->description = "";
        $assetModel->save(false);
    } else if ($input['action'] === 'delete') {
        $assetModel->status = "deleted";
        $assetModel->save(false);
    }

    echo json_encode($input);
    return \yii\helpers\Json::encode([
        'message' => 'success',
    ]);
}
```

I really don't know how to figure this out. How do I pass the id to the controller? I hope you understand this. Please let me know if you have questions. If you have other idea for the implementation, let me know as well.

Comment: if you are passing it as a `parameter` then I guess your `url` should be `var urlID = "../save-inline-edit?" + file[0].assetID;` i.e. with `?` appended.

Comment: In yii2, specifically in this project I am working, the urls and prettified and ID's are passed after the slash following name of the action which is in my case `../save-inline-edit/[ID]`

Comment: Not sure but your action name seems to be `actionSaveInlineEdit` and in `urlID` its `save-inline-edit`?

Comment: That's the equivalent in yii2's function naming

Comment: Basically error says you are not giving the `id` parameter to action.. Not sure how to pass with `yii2` since I have no knowledge in it..

Answer (score 1):

As you put the id as file.assetID in start of code and get the id using file[0].assetID

please use file.assetID to get the id in url.

Thanks

Comment: Hello, thanks. Yes, but how do I pass it to the controller?

Comment: var urlID = "../save-inline-edit/";
use ex extra parameter like
 url: urlID,
 data: {id: file.assetID},


like this

Comment: I just tried your suggestion. But the problem is that I'm having problem in passing `id` to the controller which is in the `url`. I still get the same error.

Comment: Looks like you should use the `GET` method to send data to the server side. But Tabledit uses the `POST` method instead. But I may wrong)